# Oracle - Split records based on overlapping ranges

Tags: sql, oracle

Data sample:

```
   id   lowerlimt   upperlimit
    1   5           10  ---Master Record
    2   8           12
    3   3           8
    4   8           9
    5   11          15
```

In the above table, Let us assume record with `id=1` as Master Record. I want Compare the other records with the first record in the same table, and Split each record if it overlaps the range and assign a flag. If it overlaps assign `'Y'`, else `'N'`.
If it overlaps partially split the record in to two, one for overlapping range and other for the non-overlapping range.

```
id  lowerlimt   upperlimit  flag
2   8           10          y
2   10          12          n
3   3           5           n
3   5           8           y
4   8           9           y
5   11          15          n
```

Comment: So the Master Record will always have id=1, and it will always be present? Then: an interval may have to be split in three (for example the interval from 2 to 15). Right? And if a record just "touches" the Master Record, like 2 to 5, how is it treated? Is the flag `n`, and the result is a single row, or is the flag `y` and we show a record from 5 to 5?

Comment: Also, is the flag for the original record, or for the resulting pieces? The text says "assign flag to the records" (seemingly implying to the original records), but the output shows the flag assigned to each piece.

Comment: @mathguy Yes..  If forgot to mention the test case for interval from 2 to 15. Also in the target table we can avoid the master record

Comment: OK - can you please clarify also about the flag? Take the interval 2 to 15, it overlaps with the master record - is the flag Y? Or do you mean, as you show in the "desired output", that the portion from 2 to 5 gets the flag N, then the piece from 5 to 10 the flag Y, and the remaining portion from 10 to 12 the flag N?

Comment: @mathguy For the interval 2 to 15,the portion from 2 to 5 gets the flag N, then the piece from 5 to 10 the flag Y, and the remaining portion from 10 to 12 the flag N. We have to split the record.

Comment: OK - I modified the answer so that the flag is assigned to each fragment of an interval rather than to the original interval itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added more "test data" for testing and illustration. The main computation is to break down the input ranges into up to three pieces (some of those don't make sense and are eliminated in the final stage - the maximum of three is reached when the input range is strictly overlapping the Master Record in both directions).

For efficiency, it is best if each input row is accessed just once. So, instead of using `union all` (the easiest route), I prefer to create all three subranges and corresponding flags simultaneously, with the result having nine columns instead of three for the subranges and flags. Then I use `unpivot` to put them into separate rows.

```
with
      test_data ( id, lowerlimit, upperlimit ) as (
        select 1,  5, 10 from dual union all ---Master Record
        select 2,  8, 12 from dual union all
        select 3,  3,  8 from dual union all
        select 4,  8,  9 from dual union all
        select 5, 11, 15 from dual union all
        select 6,  2,  5 from dual union all
        select 7,  1, 14 from dual
      )
-- end of test data (not part of the solution)
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE (use your actual table name)
select id, lowerlimit, upperlimit, flag
from (
   select id,
                   t.lowerlimit        as x1, least(t.upperlimit, m.ll) as y1, 'n' as f1,
          greatest(t.lowerlimit, m.ll) as x2, least(t.upperlimit, m.ul) as y2, 'y' as f2,
          greatest(t.lowerlimit, m.ul) as x3,       t.upperlimit        as y3, 'n' as f3
   from   test_data t cross join
          ( select lowerlimit ll, upperlimit ul 
            from   test_data
            where  id = 1
          ) m
   where  t.id != 1
     )
unpivot ( ( lowerlimit, upperlimit, flag )
                        for ( x, y, f ) in ( ( x1, y1, f1), (x2, y2, f2), (x3, y3, f3) ) )
where lowerlimit < upperlimit
order by id, lowerlimit   --  if needed
;
```

**Output**:

```
ID LOWERLIMIT UPPERLIMIT FLAG
-- ---------- ---------- ----
 2          8         10 y
 2         10         12 n
 3          3          5 n
 3          5          8 y
 4          8          9 y
 5         11         15 n
 6          2          5 n
 7          1          5 n
 7          5         10 y
 7         10         14 n

10 rows selected.
```

Comment: Can u xplain the cross join part?

Comment: The cross join (to the single-row result of a subquery) is just so I can have access to the values for `id=1`. It is similar to the use of variables in a procedural programming language. If I need to extract a bit of data from a table - for example the values from one row - I will write a subquery to select just that row, and do a cross join to it so I can use those values as "variables". A very common usage, by the way - nothing I invented (and nothing out of the ordinary).

Comment: But the way you implemented this logic with the use of unpivot is extra ordinary. Awesome!!!

Comment: Using `unpivot` instead of repeated `union all` is also a common trick (although less so, perhaps, than the cross join trick) - I didn't invent it, I learned it from others. It allows us to read the base table just once, instead of several times - and in many cases, "reading the base table" is the most time-consuming part of a query. Available only in Oracle 11.1 and above though, since `pivot` and `unpivot` were only introduced in Oracle 11.1.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to split this into three overlapping conditions, essentially "before", "during", and "after".  Because you want multiple different *rows* for each existing row, you can do this using `union all`:

```
select t.id, t.lowerlimit,
       least(tm.lowerlimit, t.upperlimit) as upperlimit,
       'n' as overlaps
from t join
     t tm
     on t.id <> 1 and tm.id = 1 and
        t.lowerlimit < tm.lowerlimit
union all
select t.id,
       greatest(t.lowerlimit, tm.lowerlimit),
       least(t.upperlimit, tm.upperlimit), 'y' as overlaps
from t join
     t tm
     on t.id <> 1 and tm.id = 1 and
        t.lowerlimit <= tm.lowerlimit and
        t.upperlimit >= tm.upperlimit
union all
select t.id, greatest(tm.upperlimit, t.upperlimit),
       t.upperlimit, 'n'
from t join
     t tm
     on t.id <> 1 and tm.id = 1 and
        t.upperlimit > tm.upperlimit;
```

Comment: Besides missing `id` in `tm.id` (you have `tm = 1` in three places, but `tm` is a table alias), the logic doesn't work. You can test it for yourself, using the CTE in my answer (I named it `test_data` instead of `t` so you will have to change that first). For example, for the input `id=2`, it produces a single interval, from 12 to 12.

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi - What do you mean by "is working"? It still produces the same incorrect result for `id=2` as I pointed out earlier, and it still does not produce **any** output for `id=4`. It is pretty obvious Gordon did NOT test his answer, as I suggested.

Comment: upperlimit = lowerlimit records are coming after the query is ran. With @mathguy 's test data, I could see the query fails case for ids (2,5,7)

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi - it fails for id = 4 also. It's your problem, you could do a better job of inspecting the different solutions for correctness.